How can I run a .NET console application with arguments in a process on macOS from a .NET MAUI application?
I'm working on a .NET MAUI application and need to run a .NET console application in a separate process on macOS. On Windows, I achieved this using Process.Start by running the exe filepath of my console application with the following code:
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(exePath, args) { WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden });
However, I'm not sure how to accomplish the same task on macOS. Is there any workaround for macOS to run this console application? I created this console application within the same solution of my .NET Maui project.
Here’s what I need:

Run a .NET console application in a process while closing the main application.
Pass arguments to the application.
Ensure the application runs in the background (not visible to the user).

Additional Information:

The application is a .NET MAUI application.
The target console application is a .NET 8 application.


What doesn't work when you do Process.Start(...)? I don't have access to a macOS machine myself but judging from the docs and other questions Process.Start itself is cross-platform and should just work.

There is no exe file on macOS. I tried running the dll file.
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("dotnet", $"{dllFilePath} {args}")
{
WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
});
Didn't work. The process should start while closing the application.

What didn't work? Did you get an exception? Did something print to the stdout/ stderr of the Process? Is there any error message? Anyways you need to dotnet run path/to/dll, just dotnet doesn't work. You may also want to think about publishing your console project as a single file with the runtime embedded.

Have you tried using the full path for dotnet executable?

For macOS, which path of dotnet executable should I run?
